# The best way to reorder arrays within array through a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Say I have the following array

```
[{
   'id'=>1
   'order'=>0
   'name'=>'john'
   'date_created'=>'2015-12-8'
 },
 {
   'id'=>1
   'order'=>3
   'name'=>'sam'
   'date_created'=>'2015-12-11'
 },
 {
   'id'=>1
   'order'=>1
   'name'=>'allen'
   'date_created'=>'2015-12-11'
 },
 {
   'id'=>1
   'order'=>2
   'name'=>'mick'
   'date_created'=>'2015-12-11'
 },
 {
   'id'=>1
   'order'=>0
   'name'=>'fred'
   'date_created'=>'2015-12-11'
 },
 {
   'id'=>1
   'order'=>0
   'name'=>'sarah'
   'date_created'=>'2015-12-14'
 }
]
```

The backend retrieves by date_created. I want to reorder if order > 0 only on the same date_created. So if dates are equal and there is an order then sort that section of the array.

My current attempt is the following:

```
   function sortArray(array) {

        var newarray = [];
        var sortarray = [];

        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            if(!array[i].order) newarray.push(array[i]);
            else {
                if(i+1 !== array.length && array[i].date === array[i+1].date && array[i+1].order > 0) sortarray.push(array[i]);
                else {
                    sortarray.push(array[i]);
                    sortarray.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a.order>b.order;
                    });
                    newarray = newarray.concat(sortarray);
                }
            }
        }
        return newarray;
    }
```

I feel like this could be done a lot better. My first post on here so I might have missed how I'm supposed to do this, please let me know if it needs correcting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommend using the [built-in Array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) instead of inventing your own.

Comment: If possible, have the backend do `ORDER BY date_created, order`, so you don't have to write any code.

Comment: @Chris, the problem is I need the sort to only be done on the same date_created dates. I'm not sure how the built in Array sort helps this.

Comment: @Kenney I tried ORDER BY date_created,order in Laravels eloquent ORM and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @user5514813 - the answer by jfriend00 below captures exactly what I was trying to refer to, but didn't have enough time to elaborate on. Glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing your data declaration to be legal Javascript, you can use a custom callback for the built-in `array.sort()`.  The custom callback sorts by two keys, first by `date_created`, then if those are equal, it sorts by order.

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = Date.parse(a.date_created);
    var dateB = Date.parse(b.date_created);
    if (dateA !== dateB) {
        return dateA - dateB;
    } else {
        // if dates are equal, sort by order
        return +a.order - +b.order;
    }
});
```

And, a working snippet you can actually run:

```js
var data = [{
   'id':1,
   'order':0,
   'name':'john',
   'date_created':'2015-12-8'
 },
 {
   'id':1,
   'order':3,
   'name':'sam',
   'date_created':'2015-12-11'
 },
 {
   'id':1,
   'order':1,
   'name':'allen',
   'date_created':'2015-12-11'
 },
 {
   'id':1,
   'order':2,
   'name':'mick',
   'date_created':'2015-12-11'
 },
 {
   'id':1,
   'order':0,
   'name':'fred',
   'date_created':'2015-12-11'
 },
 {
   'id':1,
   'order':0,
   'name':'sarah',
   'date_created':'2015-12-14'
 }
]

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = Date.parse(a.date_created);
    var dateB = Date.parse(b.date_created);
    if (dateA !== dateB) {
        return dateA - dateB;
    } else {
        // if dates are equal, sort by order
        return +a.order - +b.order;
    }
});

log(data);

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(x);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

If you don't actually want the primary sort to be `date_created`, but would rather they keep their current order (whatever it is), then that could be done too (I wasn't quite sure from your question which you wanted).

Comment: Brilliant, that's perfect. Worked a treat. Not sure why but 
else {
        // if dates are equal, sort by order
        return +a.order - +b.order;
    }
isn't making much sense to me.

Comment: @user5514813 - The  extra `+` signs in `+a.order - +b.order;` just allows the `order` property to be a string and the `+` does a conversion to a number.  If you know the properties are always an actual number, you can remove those two `+` signs.  For some reason, when I wrote the code, I thought they were strings, not numbers so the conversion was required, but it appears to maybe not be needed.  It does no harm to be there.

Comment: Thx @jfriend00 - that's exactly what I was thinking of in my comment, but was too preoccupied at work to elaborate on. I had hoped it would be enough for someone to build on :)